# When placing a UITableView inside UIView the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never hit

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, ios7

I have done some extensive research and am aware about the pitfalls when working with a plain `UITableViewController`. I also found similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072401/can-you-add-a-uitableviewcontrollers-tableview-to-another-view) that have been answered without any luck. I must be missing something very trivial.

I have uploaded the [test project](https://github.com/houmie/iTestTable) on Github.

My goal is to put the UITableView inside a UIView.

[image]

I have a xibfile and have the file's owner set to my viewcontroller, and wired everything up.

```
@interface TNViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

That's how the view controller's implementation looks like.

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"TNViewController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }    
    return cell;
}
```

In App delegate I am running it like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    TNViewController *vc = [TNViewController new];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:vc];
     ...
}
```

However the table stays empty and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never hit. It must be related to the UIView wrapping the table, but I am not sure what I have wired up wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your test project, you made the mistake of connecting both the myTable and view outlets of the File's Owner to the table view. The view outlet should be connected to the main view (which is easier to connect to where it says view in the object list rather than on the canvas). Of course, to see anything in your table, you need to add some content to the cell.

**After Edit:**

[image]

Right click on File's Owner to bring up the black window. As you can see from the image, "view" is connected tot he table view. Click the "x" next to table view on that line to delete that connection, then drag from the open circle on the right up to where it says "View" (just below the First Responder cube).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure if I follow you, may you please elaborate on `The view outlet should be connected to the main view` or provide a screenshot how you would connect them? Alternatively feel free to change the project and commit the change. Whatever is easier. Thanks

Comment: This was my mistake. Thank you very much for clarifying it. I was expecting the problem to be the wiring, but couldn't figure out where exactly it went wrong. +1

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look at your code and didn't see you setting delegate or datasource. Try adding below lines before you call `reloadData` and see whether `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called...

```
[uitableview setDelegate:self];
[uitableview setDataSource:self];
```

Comment: Why is it in interface? IBOutlet UITableView *myTable; Can you declare it as a property - @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable; Then somewhere before reloadData, make calls to set delegate and datasource - [self.myTable setDelegate:self];
[self.myTable setDataSource:self];

Comment: Thanks. I removed it from interface and added it as `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;` In `viewDidAppear` i set the delegate and datasource before reload and same problem. Have you tried the project to see if it works on your end?

Answer (score 1):

just make Outlet for View nd TableView Properly... you havnt connected it perfectly in Your test Project...
nd change this method

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text=@"hello";

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross check if your xib name is @"TNViewController" (should be same as used during object initialization below) and also correct this function

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

and check the `TNViewController` initialization line in this function.

```
 (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    TNViewController *vc = [[TNViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TNViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:vc];
     ...
}
```

Comment: put breakpoints in `initWithNibName` , `viewDidLoad` methods and tableview data source methods - `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if debugger stops in all these function when the view loads. It should stop on all these methods.

Comment: It only breaks at `initWithNibName` and `viewDidLoad`, not in the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would have this as a comment, if I could.

From the class reference for UITableView:
UITableView overrides the layoutSubviews method of UIView so that it calls reloadData only when you create a new instance of UITableView or when you assign a new data source. Reloading the table view clears current state, including the current selection. However, if you explicitly call reloadData, it clears this state and any subsequent direct or indirect call to layoutSubviews does not trigger a reload.

Can it be you need to reloadData?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried it without any luck. I made a simple project to demo the problem. https://github.com/houmie/iTestTable